# Proper way to insert and get last id using Grails MongoDB Low Level Api

Tags: mongodb, grails

I'm trying to insert a document into mongodb with the low level api.  This works fine, but I need the _id.

```
def lesson = db.lesson.insert([
                            description: "This is a lesson",
                            title: title,
                            name: name,
                            lessonVersion: "1.0",
                            active: true
                    ])
```

How should I be doing the insert so that I can get the _id or the whole document.  I was trying to use the low level api because I need a number of dynamic fields.  I know you can do that with domain objects, but want to try this method.

Comment: just use db.lesson.findOne() right after it to get the document and get its id, the defaul ist desc on "_id" so the latest id is from the last inserted

Comment: no even better ! after the insert make "println lesson" and def lesson holds the id now ! the id is generated client-side, so you dont have to ask the server